# Return rows and columns from a 2d array using values from a 1d array in Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to use the values of a 1-dim array to slice/return the rows and columns from a 2-dim array in Numpy. For example, say I have the following one dim array:
[1,3,5)]
and the following 2 dim array:

```
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 7, 0, 10],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0],
       [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 9]])
```

How do I return the following:

```
array([[4, 0, 1],
       [1, 7, 10],
       [2, 0, 9]])
```

I would also like to be able to produce a 6x6 mask using the same example. So that I would get this:

```
array([[True, True, True, True, True, True],
       [True, False, True, False, True, False],
       [True, True, True, True, True, True],
       [True, False, True, False, True, False],
       [True, True, True, True, True, True],
       [True, False, True, False, True, False]],)
```

I have tried many different things and nothing seems to get exactly what I need. I know I could do it by writing a couple of loops, but I figured there must be an easier way. I have also done a number of searches and still no luck. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
>>> a = array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
...        [0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1],
...        [0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0],
...        [0, 1, 0, 7, 0, 10],
...        [0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0],
...        [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 9]])
>>> 
>>> a[1::2,1::2]
array([[ 4,  0,  1],
       [ 1,  7, 10],
       [ 2,  0,  9]])
```

Since your stride access is so regular, you can accomplish this with basic slicing.  As for the mask:

```
>>> a = np.ones(a.shape,dtype=bool)
>>> a[1::2,1::2] = False
>>> a
array([[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True, False,  True, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True, False,  True, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True, False,  True, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Of course, this answer is assuming you want every other element along the axis (starting with index 1).  You could modify the slice to stop when the index is 6:  `a[1:6:2,1:6:2]` or to take every 3rd element, `a[1::3,1::3]`, but if you need random access into the array, that becomes a bit harder...

You can do something like this:

```
>>> b = [1,3,5]
>>> a[:,b][b]
array([[ 4,  0,  1],
       [ 1,  7, 10],
       [ 2,  0,  9]])
>>> a[b][:,b]  #I think the same thing, but depending on data layout, one may be faster than the other
array([[ 4,  0,  1],
       [ 1,  7, 10],
       [ 2,  0,  9]])
```

At this point though, you're probably making a copy of the array rather than just getting a view.  This is less efficient and you won't be able to use it to construct the boolean mask as we did previously I don't think.

Comment: +1 But `a[b][:, b]` is the same as `a[b[:, None], b]` or some other similar variant like `a[b.reshape(-1, 1), b]`, and will spare you instantiating an intermediate array.

Comment: Great! No, my stride access is not regular so this: a[:,b][b] works. I was just using an example that would be easy to follow. My real data is larger and not regular.Like you said, this does not work for making the mask. Any suggestions? Thanks again!

Comment: I am trying to return the mean and max of a for only those cells that have a row/col position in b and it would be nice to know the index of the max value in a, given the mask.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe could be useful the routine np.meshgrid():

```
a = array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 1, 0, 7, 0, 10],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0],
   [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 9]])

b = np.array([1, 3, 5])

B = np.meshgrid(b,b)

print a[B].T

Out: [[ 4  0  1]
      [ 1  7 10]
      [ 2  0  9]]
```

I think that is the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

If you put your big array in `a` and your small one in `i`, you can do the slicing with `a[i][...,i]`. There's probably a way to do it in one step too, but I'm not enough of a numpy wizard to know it yet.

Answer (score 0):

[mgilson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17203113/400793) is what you want if you know that the strides are regular. However, if `a` is your array, and you want to get `a[i, j]` for all `i` and `j` in some 1-D array, `b`, there is a gotcha.

```
In : a = array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 7, 0, 10],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0],
       [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 9]])

In : b = np.array([1, 3, 5])

In : a[b, b]
Out: array([4, 7, 9])
```

The problem is that this just gets you elements (1, 1), (3, 3) and (5, 5). If you try doing the indexing in separate steps,

```
In : a[b][b]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-87-c3c286c42537> in <module>()
----> 1 a[b][b]

IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3
```

This error arises because I'm indexing the same axis twice. Either of these work:

```
In : a[b][:, b]
Out:
array([[ 4,  0,  1],
       [ 1,  7, 10],
       [ 2,  0,  9]])

In : a[:, b][b]
Out:
array([[ 4,  0,  1],
       [ 1,  7, 10],
       [ 2,  0,  9]])
```

The `[b]` picks out the rows, and `[:, b]` picks out the columns; these indexing operations can be swapped.